# What options do I have if I've stripped the threads for my Helicoil repair?

Tags: stripped-thread

A while back I had repaired a stripped thread on my aluminium timing chain cover with a M6x1.0 Helicoil. This involved:

- drilling out the damaged thread
- tapping a slightly larger M8x1.0 internal thread
- screwing in the M6x1.0 Helicoil

---

Lately I noticed that the Helicoil had backed out. In an attempt to "fix" this I ended up damaging the new thread.

Short of replacing the timing cover itself, is it possible to recover from this mess I've made?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possible corrective action is to use a key-locking insert (commercial name "KeySert" or "KeenSert").

For an M6x1.0 internal thread, the standard external thread is M10x1.25. The following steps will need to be taken:

- Enlarge the hole size with to 8.8mm (0.35" drill bit is close enough)
- Create new thread with an M10x1.25 tap wrench
- Screw in the locking insert until the head is flush with the surface
- Press the locks in to lock the insert in place.

Here is a YouTube video demonstrating the steps involved: http://youtu.be/UTdJUMIcrPI

[image: Key Locking Inserts]

Comment: These also also available under the brand Time-sert.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the imperial system, but I'm pretty sure that 3.5" is not close to 8.8mm by any standard ;-)