# Can metal putty be used to repair stripped threads in aluminum castings?

Tags: repair, stripped-thread

I've been burnt by stripped threads on a couple of occasions now, so knowing that metal putty could be used to re-tap a brand new thread in aluminum would be reassuring.

I recently came across [Liqui Moly Metal Putty](http://www.liqui-moly.com/liquimoly/produktdb.nsf/id/en_6187.html?OpenDocument&land=gb). The data sheet says:

> Liqui Moly Metal Putty is a firmly adherent, 2-component epoxy resin
>   putty with very high chemical resistance. Liqui Moly Metal Putty is
>   ideally suitable for permanent, quick repairs such as sealing cracks
>   or repairing damaged threaded holes in iron, cast iron and other
>   surfaces. Also suitable for magnesium. After curing, the repaired site
>   can be further processed by milling or grinding etc. and painted over.

The lack of mention of aluminum here is a bit little strange. I don't expect there to be any issues in using the product with aluminum, but as I haven't tried it I cannot be sure.

Am I being overly cautious, or is there a reason to be concerned here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a lack of the word *aluminum*. I don't think you'd have any issue using it in aluminum though. I think that falls under *other surfaces* portion.

As for the fix, if at all possible, I'd use something to the effect of a [Helicoil](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00K3263WY) instead. It will have a lot better longevity than the putty would. The kit in the link has several different sizes to work with. You can get kits of a single size. Also, Helicoil is just one brand ... there are others out there as well. Helicoil has been around a long time and has a great reputation.

Comment: Good advice there with the Helicoil, but sometimes you just [don't have that luxury](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/9423/what-options-do-i-have-if-ive-stripped-the-threads-for-my-helicoil-repair).

Comment: @Zaid - Oh, I agree. The ones you show in that thread are the solid ones. They take up way too much space, IMHO. With the Helicoil brand, you only take out what you need. Sometimes, that's too much as well '-)

Comment: They're also handy if you break a [motor mount bolt](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/3742/57)....