# Stripped out head for rocker arm bolt

Tags: buick, century, cylinder-head

I have a rocker arm in my '03 Century Custom that has stripped out the head. I tried to tap it and helicoil it but unfortunately the tap went sideways. I am thinking that I may be able to drill and tap it out to a larger size. My question is, can I tap this out to a larger size and use an m10 1.25 helicoil with an m8 1.25 helicoil. If not, is there a way for me to do this.

Comment: Try something like an [EZ-Lock](https://www.ezlok.com/inserts-for-metal/solid-threaded-inserts). The insert is solid and larger than an Helicoil. As long as you drill straight and there's enough meat left in the boss, it should be just peachy.

Comment: One option is to use a keysert, as shown in [this question](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/9423/675).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you held the tap or drill for your first effort, but you should use a drill press and mount the head such that the boss you need to work on is perpendicular so that whatever insert you plan to fit goes in correctly this time.